# Struts ActionMessage

Tags: struts

Hi I have a struts 1.X app, and in order to show errors detected in an action class, I use:

```
errors.add("Error Global", new ActionMessage("some_string_in_properties_file"));
```

Which works just fine.

My problem is that now the string I need to send to the jsp page as error has a session variable in it (like "You have 3 more valid attempts", being 3 the session variable).

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ActionMessage constructor of 2 arguments. According to JavaDoc:

```
public ActionMessage(java.lang.String key,
                     java.lang.Object value0)

Construct an action message with the specified replacement values.

Parameters:
    key - Message key for this message
    value0 - First replacement value
```

In your case:

```
errors.add("Error Global", new ActionMessage("some_string_in_properties_file", sessionVariable));
```

`some_string_in_properties_file` should look like this:

```
some_string_in_properties_file=You have {0} more valid attempt(s)
```